# How can I solve this error created by SaveAs2?

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

My Code:

```
Sub autoopen()

    curfile = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Name

    templatefile = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Templates\" & DateDiff("s", #1/1/1970#, Now()) & ".dotm"

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=templatefile, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, AddToRecentFiles:=True

End Sub
```

After running this on the most up to date version of Windows and MS Word I get a 4189 runtime error. What could be causing this? The file this is being run from is a .docm if that could be a problem?

Comment: Why use `SaveAs2` instead of `SaveAs`? Does it work without the `2`?

Comment: Sadly no, thank you for the recommendation though

Comment: Does it work with a different folder? (like your documents folder)

Comment: What is the actual file path passed to the `SaveAs2` method? Do you get any errors when you do the same things manually?

Comment: After editing the macro I am unable to save the template to my desktop folder, the script tries to put the directory: "C:\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\time.dotm". I also tried to add the directory manually and it resulted in the same error.